# Add GoogleMaps inside ListView and fill the entire espace

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I need to add a GoogleMap view inside a ListView and want it to get the full available space on screen (without scroll)

How can I do that ?

But always receive the error about infinity height ):

This is what I tried:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics()(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 80,
            collapsedHeight: 56,
            backgroundColor: AppColors.black,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleTitleAppBar(),
          ),
        ],
        body: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                   Container(
                      color: AppColors.black,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 28, bottom: 28),
                        child: HeaderComponent(),
                      )
                   ),
                   Expanded(
                      flex: 1
                      child: GoogleMaps(
                            compassEnabled: false,
                            initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
                            gestureRecognizers: Set()
                              ..add(
                                Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(
                                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            markers: markers,
                          );
                   ),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
         );
```

Comment: If you do not need to scroll, why use ListView, have you tried replacing listView with simple Column?

Comment: Yeah, same error for Column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try wrap the listview widget with SizedBox. And then give the
SizedBox's height-width value using MediaQuery or just static number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your Scaffold variables to run at my end. Make the necessary changes your end. Here's the solution. Try with this. I have replaced ListView with Column.

```
 PreferredSizeWidget customAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: const Text('APPBAR TITLE HERE'),
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
    );
  }

  Widget flexibleTitleAppBar() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue.shade900,
    );
  }

  Widget headerComponent() {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: customAppBar(),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 80,
            collapsedHeight: 56,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            flexibleSpace: flexibleTitleAppBar(),
          ),
        ],
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 16, right: 16, top: 28, bottom: 28),
                  child: headerComponent(),
                )),
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  compassEnabled: false,
                  initialCameraPosition:
                      const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0, 0)),
                  gestureRecognizers: Set()
                    ..add(
                      Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  markers: const <Marker>{},
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```